# Folder view in ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: java, android

I want to go to a certain folder in the application I wrote in android studio.I want to go where my folders are.I want to go back to where the folders are in not accessing the data in it. for example "my files - internal storage - downloads". I want to open it. Would you suggest a source way or function, which I can use for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try device file explorer https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer

hope this helps